# R - Selectively combine columns of matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Is there a way to combine columns of a matrix as per the below:

Input:

```
m1
         [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
S 121.0000000 100.0000000 100.0000000 82.6446281
P   0.5224135   0.1790449   0.1737533  0.1247883
```

Output:

```
m2
         [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
S 121.0000000 100.0000000  82.6446281 
P   0.5224135   0.3527982   0.1247883
```

I need to combine the elements of row 2 based on equal elements in row 1.

In this case, `m2[2,2] = m1[2,2] + m1[2,3]`

Thanks

Comment: Something like `tapply(m1[2, ], m1[1, ], sum)`, for your simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R , using `aggregate` for example :

```
 t(aggregate(P~S,t(dat),sum))

        [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
S 82.6446281 100.0000000 121.0000000
P  0.1247883   0.3527982   0.5224135
```

Note the use of transpose here , In general it is easier to group by column than by rows.

Answer (score 1):

This would fully implement and demonstrate @jbaums suggestion:

```
> rbind(sort( m1[1, !duplicated (m1[1,])] ), tapply(m1[2, ], m1[1, ], sum))
     82.6446281         100         121
[1,] 82.6446281 100.0000000 121.0000000
[2,]  0.1247883   0.3527982   0.5224135
```

Comment: This won't work as it is. You'll have to `sort` your `m1[1, !duplicated(m[1, ])]`.

Comment: Right you are. Fixed.